# How to get post impressions with LinkedIn API on personal profile share

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm building a platform https://blabigo.com that allows users to schedule content on LinkedIn. Now I want to build analytics for personal share. I have got access to the LinkedIn community management API but I'm not able to find a way to retrieve impressions for a post that has been posted on a personal profile. I only found it for organization pages.

I tried this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions?view=li-lms-2023-10&tabs=http and didn't find how to get impression count. It returns only likes and comments. No impressions.

It would be great if someone has a clue on how it works ... thanks!